# How to convert vector to changes in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, vector, derivative

How can I change a vector to its changes between members, easily in MATLAB?

For example I want to convert `x = [1 , 10 , 6]` to `y = [9,-4]` where `y(i) = x(i+1) - x(i)`.

Does taking the derivative provide the same result?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

You want to look into the built in function [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html).  If `x` is your vector, then `diff(x)` returns a vector of the differences `[x(2) - x(1), x(3) - x(2), ..., x(n) - x(n-1)]`.

An example of using `diff` for your vector x is as follows.

```
>> x = [1, 10, 6];
>> diff(x)

ans = [9 -4]
```

Comment: And `cumsum` is the inverse operation.

Comment: Thanks ! Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method being used here is a form of finite differencing. It is a crude numerical approximation for finding the derivative. Here all you are doing is declare an x vector. If you then run this equation on x you will get your y vector as the output.

Comment: Does this help? If so please give me a thumbs up, if not let me know where you are having trouble

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for an implementation of derivation, or the numerical approximation as you said.